# VB.NET Databound Label not updating

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I am having issues with a label with a databound text value updating. I have a Class that calculates the best throw of an athlete and this is bound to a label in my form. The class is as follows

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class Competition
    Public Sub New()
        Competitors = New List(Of Competitor)()
    End Sub
    Public Property Competitors() As List(Of Competitor)
        Get
            Return m_Competitors
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Competitor))
            m_Competitors = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Competitors As List(Of Competitor)
    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentPlacings() As List(Of Competitor)
        Get
            Return Competitors.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.BestThrow).ToList()

        End Get
    End Property

End Class
Public Class Competitor
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object,
            e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
            Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Public Sub New()
        Throws = New List(Of [Throw])()
    End Sub
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return m_FirstName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_FirstName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_LastName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_LastName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_LastName As String
    Public Property compNumber() As String
        Get
            Return m_compNumb
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_compNumb = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_compNumb As String
    Public Property club() As String
        Get
            Return m_club
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_club = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_club As String
    Public Property Throws() As List(Of [Throw])
        Get
            Return m_Throws
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of [Throw]))
            m_Throws = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Throws As List(Of [Throw])
    Public ReadOnly Property BestThrow() As Object
        Get
            Dim bt = Throws.Where(Function(t) t.Status = ThrowStatus.Valid).OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.Distance).First()
            If (IsNothing(bt.Distance)) Then
                bt.Distance = "0"
            End If
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("BestThrow"))
            Return bt

        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property getLabel
        Get
            Return compNumber & " " & LastName & ", " & FirstName & vbCrLf & club
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
Public Enum ThrowStatus
    Valid
    Pass
    Foul
End Enum
Public Class [Throw]
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Property Status() As ThrowStatus
        Get
            Return m_Status
        End Get
        Set(value As ThrowStatus)
            m_Status = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Status As ThrowStatus
    Public Property Distance() As String
        Get
            If Status = ThrowStatus.Valid Then
                If (m_Distance > 0) Then
                    Return m_Distance
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If

            ElseIf Status = ThrowStatus.Pass Then
                Return "PASS"
            ElseIf Status = ThrowStatus.Foul Then
                Return "FOUL"
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If (value > 0) Then


                If (IsNumeric(value)) Then
                    m_Distance = value
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                ElseIf (value = "foul") Then
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Foul
                ElseIf (value = "pass") Then
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Pass
                Else
                    Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
                    m_Distance = Nothing
                End If
            Else
                m_Distance = Nothing
                Status = ThrowStatus.Valid
            End If
            OnPropertyChanged("Distance")
        End Set
    End Property
    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub
    Private m_Distance As Decimal
    Public Property attempt() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_attempt
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_attempt = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_attempt As Integer

End Class
```

The line that databinds for the Label is as follows:

```
best.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", athlete.BestThrow, "distance", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

I can tell that the Property BestThrow is defintely being updated using Watch however for some reason the label seems to only reflect Throw(0).Distance and not BestThrow.Distance

I can change Throw(0) and the label will change, if I add a bigger number to any of the other 5 attempts and Watch the value I can see that the BestThrow is being updated.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a wrong prespective, property `BestThrow` is never updated because it has no setter. When you check `BestThrow` value using watch, it 'recalculated' because you request the value. What you need is to find a way to raise Property Changed event for `BestThrow` whenever item added or removed from `Throws` because `BestThrow` value depends on `Throws`. After event raised, UI will call `BestThrow's` getter again looking for updated value.

```
'You need to execute this code to notify UI that `BestThrow` value has changed
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("BestThrow"))
```

Raisng the event can be done manually after code for adding/removing item to/from `Throws` property, or you can make `Throws` an ObservableCollection of `Throw` then listen to Collection Changed event. Then in the event handler you can raise `BestThrow` property changed event.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Would raising the event when the Throw is set be sufficient to trigger the UI to update the value or do I need to somehow set the label to actively listen for the PropertyChangedEvent for BestThrow?

Comment: Raising the event should be enough. Thats how data-binding works. When using data-binding UI will be updated whenever value of a property it bound to updated, as long as it get notified that the property value has changed. And raising property changed event is the way to notify UI

Comment: After making those changes it will now refresh the label, but only on the first field being changed. So if I have 3 throws in, and the second one is the furthest it will not display the 2nd distance until I change the 1st distance (even if I change the first distance to less than all the other distances)

Comment: After a bit more playing I created a button which generated the PropertyChangedEvent on clicking for BestThrow. This also didn't force the update of the Label